# Htaccess URLRewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've a question about URL Rewriting.
When I call a URL like this now:

`http://domein.ext/error/mysql/2/class.core.php/`

It will output this in de GET variables:

```
$_GET['type'] = mysql/2/class.core.php/.php/mysql
$_GET['error'] = 2
$_GET['file'] = class.core.php
```

But the TYPE isn't correct? This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^index/password/ index.php?error=password
RewriteRule ^error/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ error.php?type=$1&error=$2&file=$3
```

How can I fix this problem?
And everything else works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you end all of your rules with `L` flag. Change your code to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index/password/?$ index.php?error=password [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^error/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ error.php?type=$1&error=$2&file=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your matches non-greedy:

```
RewriteRule ^error/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)/ error.php?type=$1&error=$2&file=$3
```